# Regex with ? quantifier inside passive group?

Tags: ruby, regex, oniguruma

I'm editing a TextMate grammar for SQL.  It currently has the regex (keywords omitted for clarify):

```
(?i:^\s*(create)\s+(aggregate|function|(unique\s+)?index|table)\s+)(['"`]?)(\w+)\4
```

This correctly matches a function definition like

```
CREATE FUNCTION similarity
```

I wanted to handle `CREATE OR REPLACE`, so I changed the regex to

```
(?i:^\s*(create(\s+or\s+replace)?)\s+(aggregate|function|(unique\s+)?index|table)\s+)(['"`]?)(\w+)\4
```

and it wouldn't match a `CREATE` or a `CREATE OR REPLACE`. I fixed it by making the new optional group passive as well:

```
(?i:^\s*(create(?i:\s+or\s+replace)?)\s+(aggregate|function|(unique\s+)?index|table)\s+)(['"`]?)(\w+)\4
```

But.. why didn't it match before? I would expect it to match, but then to possibly give me a capture group I wasn't expecting (if the outer passive-group indicator doesn't trickle down to the new inner group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was your \4--you needed to change it to a \5 when you first added the new parens.